Use custom authentication server for harbor registry
I am new to kubernetes and trying to deploy harbor on minikube using their official helm chart. I would like to use my custom docker authentication server when the docker client tries to authenticate with the harbor registry. Is there a way to configure this ?, from their docs i could not find a way to provide my auth server/ tokenRealm as one one would if using the docker registry image.
Their configmap shows that these values have been hardcoded, why do they not provide an option to configure this, is there a work around?
harbor-helm/templates/registry/registry-cm.yaml
auth:
  htpasswd:
    realm: harbor-registry-basic-realm
    path: /etc/registry/passwd

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="harbor-registry-basic-realm" # this should be my auth server address
Date: Fri, 27 Dec 2024 10:04:58 GMT
Content-Length: 87


Since the post is not about programmiing, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It may be on-topic for [sf] or DevOps.

This is not possible. Harbor acts as a proxy to docker distribution, adding its capabilities on top of distribution. E,g own auth flow.
The default auth method between harbor core and distribution is basic auth. It is the only service who should talk to distribution directly.
Bypassing harbor is a security risk and can lead to inconsistencies between what Gabor thinks it has and what is actually there.
